# How to create an image file from customized ubuntu liveUSB?

Tags: iso

I'm using **Ubuntu 13.10-amd64** on a live persistent USB stick and I want to create an image file (.iso) from my customized Ubuntu so I can burn it to a dvd later (I've already tried Partimage, Remastersys, Relinux, UCK, Clonezilla, Ubuntu builder...).

How can I manage to do that?

Comment: If you have already tried Partimage, Remastersys, Relinux, UCK, Clonezilla, Ubuntu builder, what has gone wrong?

Comment: I get error missing valid kernel or cp : input/output error : no space left on the device. As I said I'm not installing ubuntu on my HDD I just use a persistent liveUSB so I can't even use Partimage, UCK.

Comment: Well it seems that I can't remaster from USB!!